# How do i execute a method in a class from another method in a different class?

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

I would like a text to be updated when i press the search button. But I can't figure out how. Can someone explain what Im doing wrong on a kindergarden level?

Here is some code, I guess it explains what I like to do.

```
class One():
  def setText(self, text):
    self.text.config(state=NORMAL)
    self.text.delete(1.0,END)
    self.text.insert(END, text)
    self.text.config(state=DISABLED)
  def print(self):
    self.setText('You are now searching.')
class PopUp():
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.searchButton = Button(command=self.onSearch, text ='search')
  def onSearch(self):
    mainClass = One()
    mainClass.print()
```

Comment: How is what you have not working?

Comment: Class definitions don't get run unless you use them somewhere.

Comment: I get this error message when i press the button.
    mainClass = PCMsyntax()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'